# How to add environment variables to actor.yaml file in opentest?

Tags: opentest

Is there a way to add environment variable into an actor.yaml file? To manage some information through system variables?

For example to manage the encryptionPassword parameter.

I am not sure if this I can get work in other way that is not through opentest options.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.